# Finding rows with latest date by id mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these 2 tables I am trying to write a query that will help me select all rows that gives this result

**users**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | test |
| 2 | test2 |

**logs**

| id | userId | message | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | this is a test | 2020-10-07 12:57:14 |
| 2 | 1 | another reason | 2020-10-07 13:57:14 |
| 3 | 1 | another reason 2 | 2020-10-07 14:57:14 |
| 4 | 2 | another reason 3 | 2020-10-04 12:57:14 |
| 5 | 2 | another reason 4 | 2020-10-05 12:57:14 |
| 6 | 2 | another reason 4 | 2020-10-06 12:57:14 |

**Output Table**
I need to pass many user Ids like in this case (1,2) and get below table only return MAX (date) per row per userId

| id | userId | message | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | another reason 2 | 2020-10-07 14:57:14 |
| 6 | 2 | another reason 4 | 2020-10-06 12:57:14 |

Is this possible with one Query? This what I have but not working

```
SELECT 
id ,
userId ,
message,
date
FROM logs
WHERE userId IN (1,2)
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the results of a window function  ROW_NUMBER to retrieve these results.

```sql
SELECT
    id,userId,message,date
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY userId
            ORDER BY date DESC
        ) as rn
    FROM 
        logs
) t
WHERE rn=1 AND
      userId IN (1,2)
ORDER BY date DESC
```

and for older mysql versions

```sql
SELECT
    id,userId,message,date
FROM (
    SELECT 
        l.*,
        @row_num:=IF(userId=@prev_user_id,@row_num+1,1) as rn,
        @prev_user_id:=userId
    FROM 
        logs l
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT @row_num:=0, @prev_user_id:=NULL
    ) as vars
    ORDER BY userId, date DESC
    
) t
WHERE rn=1 AND
      userId IN (1,2)
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: not working I am getting error on
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(
            PARTITION BY

Comment: What version of mysql are you using?

Comment: mysql 5.7.34 thats one

Comment: I've added an alternative for older mysql versions. Let me know if this works for you.